# Issue with Code Optimization in STM32CubeIDE for STM32

Tags: gcc, stm32, compiler-optimization

I have written code for my STM32 that manages the settings of an external circuit via SPI. When I use the Og optimization setting in STM32CubeIDE (which uses GCC), everything works as expected, and the external chip functions correctly. However, if I switch the optimization to O1 - O3, the circuit suddenly doesn't behave as it should.

I'm at a loss for how to solve this problem. With optimization turned on, it's nearly impossible to step through the code effectively to check if all settings of the chip are correct. I need to keep the optimization on because without it, another part of the code takes too long to execute.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to proceed in this situation? Thank you for the advice.

Comment: You could put that another part of the code into a separate file, and compile it with more aggressive optimization, separately.

Comment: Ah, if I understand correctly, in CubeIDE, I just need to select the file, right-click on it, and set the optimization? Is it really that simple? If so, thank you very much

Comment: Compile with `gcc -O2 -fsanitize=undefined` to look for things in your code that aren't safe.  When optimization "breaks your code" (aka reveals bugs), it's usually because it relied on undefined behaviour.  (I'm not sure ubsan will work well in a freestanding program, though; it might rely on libraries.  But any parts of your code that can be unit-tested in normal programs on your dev machine should be tested with that build option.)

Comment: If you are facing this kind of problem, it is likely that you have some variables that should be declared with `volatile` specifier, for example, those variables used within the interrupt ISR function.

Comment: By going for the quick'n'easy solution i.e. optimizing selectively, you are leaving the original problem unsolved. That problem is in fact a bug, which may later bite you, so I recommend you to find it now. "Nearly impossible" is not impossible, and there are many more debugging techniques such as toggling a pin (aka the mcu printf) available, rather than just relying on single-stepping and observing variables possibly incorrectly interpreted by the debugger.

Comment: Another common problem that might have symptoms like this is if you have some kind of "delay loop" that does nothing, and gets optimised away. You should use proper delays (e.g. a timer) rather than hoping for the best with a loop.